# Angular Material input styles when populate with data

Tags: material-design, angular-material

When populate data, labels don't move and mix with data:

```
<label class="control-label">email</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="email">
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using `mat-form-field` as the parent for your `input`?

Comment: Only input. It is MDB